# How James Bond can survive from this?

Tags: james-bond, spectre

In a scene, blofeld drilled into james bond's skull and brain

How is it possible that a human being can survive that injury and damage?

Comment: It's not rocket science.

Answer (score 1):

There are many real life incidents of people taking nails to the brain without any immediate or lasting effects.  It is no real surprise he was able to survive that injury.

[Example 1](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/news/offbeat/2005-01-16-nail-skull_x.htm)

[Example 2](http://gizmodo.com/5878217/this-guy-didnt-know-he-shot-himself-in-the-head-with-a-nail-gun)

Besides that...He's James Bond... He can't very well have any lasting effects from it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Trepanning had been used in medicine since prehistory. It is still in use nowadays in some cranial surgery, like subdural hematomes. We can infer that people survive from the procedure.

Source: [Trepanning on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trepanning)